# Problem with refresh in iPhone RSS reader app

Tags: iphone, uitableview, rss, refresh, reload

I am playing around with this tutorial I found on a website. It is an RSS Feed application. Here's the link: [RSS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)

I have got the RSS Feed working in my application. I got curious and instead of having a normal refresh button, I opted for a pull down refresh. [PullDownRefresh Tutorial](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

I implemented into the RSS feed. All looks good and working but just not refreshing. So I tried adding some code in in order to make it refresh when I pull the tableview down.

The code I put is:

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource {

//should be calling your tableviews data source model to reload.
//put here just for demo.
[self performSelector:@selector(refresh)];
_reloading = YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But this duplicates the feeds.

I tried to clear my datasource prior to this with `self.tableView.dataSource = nil;` but adding this crashes it here:

`- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

```
[_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] 
                                                           options:0 error:&error];

    if (doc == nil) { 
        NSLog(@"Failed to parse %@", request.url);
    } else {

        NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];                
     NSSortDescriptor *itemSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"articleDate" ascending:YES];
     NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:itemSort,nil];
     [entries sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

                int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                    RSSEntry *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                    RSSEntry *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                    return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                }];

                [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];

                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]] //Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT".
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            }                            
        }];
    }        
}];
}`
```

The output window says this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted).'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];    
self.title= NSLocalizedString(@"News feeds", @"Storage");   
self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init ] autorelease];
self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"feed://www.yourfeed.com/feed.xml",
              nil];    

[self.tableView reloadData];

// Add the right reload button
UIBarButtonItem *reloadButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Refresh")                                            
                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                       target:self 
                       action:@selector(viewDidLoad)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = reloadButton;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
[reloadButton release];

[self refresh];

}
```